# Finding the corresponding value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to find the name of the car which has maximum mpg.  I want to print 'Toyota' which has maximum mpg.  I want to do this in a Pythonic way.  I don't like to use pandas.

Here is my code:

```
dataset=[]
f= open('auto-mpg-data.csv')
csv_f=csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    dataset.append(row)

#reading column
mpg=[]
for row in dataset:
    mpg.append(float(row[0]))
a=max(mpg)

for a in dataset:
    print(carname)
```

This is my data:

[image: This is my data]

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you don't like `pandas`, but, for completeness sake, here is how you could have used [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the CSV file into a *dataframe* (which is quite *convenient when dealing with tabular data*) and then get the `carname` value for the maximum `mpg` value:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('cars.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
print(df.loc[df['mpg'].idxmax()]['carname'])
```

Prints `'Toyota'` for the provided sample CSV.

Comment: OP clearly stated that he doesn't want to use pandas. Not to mention that installing pandas for such a simple task is truely an overkill.

Comment: @freakish Python's PyPI rich database of third-party packages is one of the greatest things about the language. Not to mention having a dataframe being convenient to work with a tabular data such as in this case. If the OP does not want to use pandas, it is perfectly okay. But for others coming to this thread, this may be a good option. I'll add a note about that. Thanks for putting a comment, explicit is better than implicit :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to improve your code:

1. When you are working with files, it's always best to [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) your file after working with it, or wrap your snippet of code in a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) block.  This closes your file automatically.
2. You are iterating multiple times through the lines in your file, which isn't necessary.  There are much more performant approaches to solve your problem.

This code worked for me:

```
import csv

with open('auto-mpg-data.csv','r') as f:
    csv_f = list(csv.reader(f))

    best_mpg = 0
    best_row = 0

    for i,j in enumerate(csv_f):
        if i == 0:
            continue

        best_mpg = max(best_mpg, float(j[0]))

        if best_mpg == float(j[0]):
            best_row = i

print (csv_f[best_row][3])

# Output:
# 'Toyota'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, every object that supports iteration, can be converted directly to a list using the `list` function. Hence instead of

```
for row in csv_f:
    dataset.append(row)
```

you can do:

```
dataset = list(csv_f)
```

Next, since `dataset` is a list of rows (each row is a list), you can use Python's `max` function to find the maximum row provided that the key to check against is the float value of the first number on each row, like so:

```
max_row = max(dataset, key=lambda row: float(row[0]))
```

max_row holds the row with maximum mpg

Answer (score 0):

The simplies way:

```
with open('auto-mpg-data.csv') as fo:
   reader = csv.reader(fo)
   next(reader)  # skip the header
   biggest_row = max(reader, key=lambda row: float(row[0]))

print(biggest_row[3])  # or whatever the index is
```

Note that if your csv contains an incorrect data then this will fail so in order to make it fault-tolerant you would have to write a manual loop over `reader` instead of `max` and validate each `row` inside.

Also if you've already loaded the file then you can use `next` and `max` on lists as follows:

```
reader = iter(dataset)
next(reader)  # skip the header
biggest_row = max(reader, key=lambda row: float(row[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop iterator...

```
>>> mpg = [12,34,40.5,6]
>>> idx,maxMpg = 0,0
>>> for n,v in enumerate(mpg):
...  if v>maxMpg: idx,maxMpg = n,v
...
>>> idx
2
>>> maxMpg
40.5
>>> carnames = ['ford','bmw','toyota','bugatti']
>>> carnames[idx]
'toyota'
>>>
```

Using list comprehensions:...

```
>>> maxMpg = max(mpg)
>>> maxMpgId = [maxMpg == m for m in mpg]
>>> maxMpgId
[False, False, True, False]
>>> carname = [carnames[n] for n,m in enumerate(mpg) if maxMpg == m]
>>> carname
['toyota']
```

Nasty one liner...

```
carname = [carnames[n] for n,m in enumerate(mpg) if max(mpg) == m]
```